# Issue while using print function for class level function

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

For this code:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=10
        self.b=20

    def display(self):
        print(self.a)
        print(self.b)
```

when I use `print(t.display())` it gives me `10,20,None`.
I don't understand why `None` is appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Every function returns `None` by default. If you print a function with no return statement, the function returns `None` and then prints `None`.